# Making a file readable only by JavaScript and/or Flash

Tags: javascript, flash, filesystem-access

I'm a bit new to web development so forgive the slightly beginner question.  Can anyone give me some general pointers on how to prevent downloading of files while displaying content with JavaScript/Flash widgets?

The basic dilemma is making files playable by page widgets while preventing direct downloads of the source media.  However, since JavaScript and Flash are browser-side instead of server-side, I'm not sure how I can do this.

Obfuscating the source file name is another option, but I'm not sure what a good way to do this would be.  Maybe hiding with an algorithm in the .swf files?  Not sure how immune to reverse compilation .swf is though.

Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, you can't. There are two types of downloads; normal (direct) one and the one via streaming.

I would advise you to use the direct one but passing an authorization key with it.

An example of such a URL would look like:

```
/download?file=134&auth=A34C56E4FCD3908DA
    ^         ^          ^
    |         |          '- The predefined access token
    |         '- The requested file
    '- Gateway script
```

Don't forget that you must store the sensitive files somewhere outside of your document root.

The gateway script would look like (pseudo-code):

```
if( validate_token( get('auth') ){

    file_id = get('file');
    file_name = get_file_name( file_id );
    data = file_read_all( file_name );

}
```

Comment: Thanks for looking over my question.  I take it the gateway download script "fileserver" would be something like php code?  Is there any way to make PHP (or some other server-side language) appear as a file?

Comment: Yes, it can be PHP, or a flash server. Anything that can be execute don the server. I'm not sure what you mean by "appear as a file". If you want to camouflage the script, you can use Apache ReWrite Engine using `.htaccess` files.

Comment: I'm looking over PHP functions and it looks like fpassthru() might be what I need.  Basically have fpassthru() act as the intermediary to serve files.

Comment: Ah, right, that's what you need. You can use `readfile()` as well, but I hear `fpassthru()` works better. Also, you will want to to a `header('Content-Type: <mimetype>');` to make this work better. Substitute <mimetype> with the one associated to your file type.

Comment: Thanks a bunch.  I'm going to use time-sensitive encrypted tokens and force the files to start loading as soon as the page loads.

Comment: OK. Don't forget to mark my answer as the right one if it helped!

Answer (score 1):

if your intention is to prevent somebody stole your source code, you can't do anything, because javascript NEED to be downloaded by browser. you can translate your critical code to some server-side language and pass to brwoser (or flash) only his output. Or try some server-side javascript engine